# A loop seems to never break/system is overloaded

Tags: javascript

At school, we have to write a function that would encrypt a certain message by moving each letter of the message by an 'nC' (or niveauCryptage) number in the alphabet.

Currently, whenever I execute the code, I am stuck on a forever loading screen after completing both of the user interactions (the ones that ask the number by which the letters will be shifted in the alphabet & the message the user wants to encrypt). I suspect that something is wrong with the loops.

```js
function crypter(t, l, nC) {
    //This function receives the alphavet Table, a letter, and the number by which the letter has to be shifted in the alphabet.
    //This function returns a single crypted letter...
    var crypte = '';
    var i = 0;

    while (t[i] != l) {
        i++;
    }

    if (i + nC > t.length) {
        crypte = (i + nC) - (t.length);
    } else {
        crypte = i + nC;
    }

    return crypte;
}

//Global variables
var tAlphaB = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L',
    'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z', ' '
];
var niveauCryptage = 0;
var texteBase = '';
var tTexteAvant = new Array();
var tTexteApres = [];
var txt = 'Le résultat du cryptage est : \n\n';

//Main program
//Ask the user to specify the number by which the letters of the message have to be shifted in the alphabet
//This number has to be a number between 1 and 10 (1 and 10 included)
do {

    niveauCryptage = parseFloat(prompt("Saisissez un nombre entre 1 et 10 pour selectionner le niveau de cryptage"));

} while (isNaN(niveauCryptage) || niveauCryptage > 10 || niveauCryptage < 1)


//Ask the user to enter a message on the condition that it is a chain of characters
do {
    texteBase = prompt("Quel texte voudrez-vous crypter?");

} while (!isNaN(texteBase))

//Transform the message into the table tTexteAvant using the split('') function
tTexteAvant = new Array(texteBase.split(''));

//Encrypt each letter of the table, tTexteAvant, into a new table, tTexteApres          
var j = 0;
while (j < tTexteAvant.length) {
    tTexteApres.push(crypter(tAlphaB, tTexteAvant[j], niveauCryptage));
    j++;

}
```

Comment: Your alphabet array only contains capital letters. If you're passing a lowercase letter to the function along with your uppercase alphabet, it will cause an infinite loop. Also it's not really a good idea to allow the possibility of creating an infinite loop just by passing different parameters to a function. I would either define the array as a constant inside of the function, or call the global variable directly instead of expecting it to be passed as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The `tTexteAvant = new Array(texteBase.split(''));` will create an array with a single item which will be the array with the characters.

You most likely want `tTexteAvant = texteBase.split('');`

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comment of Jesse, this part in the `crypter` function goes on infinite loop when the character `l` is not in the array, that is when it is a lowercase or punctuation character, for instance.

```
while (t[i] != l) {
  i++;
}
```

If you just need to find if an element of a string is present in an array you might replace that part with an array function that finds the value and returns the index in the array (or -1 if not found):

```
i = t.indexOf(l);
```

Then, you should decide what to do with the invalid or unrecognized characters or prompt the user to enter a valid string (only uppercase alphabet characters and spaces). You could also decide to transform any lowercase characters to uppercase, if this is acceptable.

As a side note, check the return value of the `crypter` function: it returns the new index and not the new letter. As commented at the beginning of the function, this is not the expected behaviour.